# Changing label text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application, using Xcode 4.6 to code in Objective-C. I have two screens connected by a push segue. In the first one I have a text field that will be filled by the user, and in the second one I have a label, and I want to fill that label text with the first screen text box text. I have also 1 class for each screen, so I have the FirstController.h, FirstController.m, SecondController.h, SecondController.m.

Answer (score 0):

As you are going from the first view controller to the second, you can expose your label as a property in your second view controller and then set that label during your first view controller's method (you need to subclass this) named:

[`[UIViewController prepareForSegue: sender:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a)

Comment: How do I subclass? I'm sorry I'm new to Objective-C

Comment: You've already subclassed if you have a "`SecondViewController`" (which is a subclass of "`UIViewController`"), which many starter apps automatically come with. Sounds like you are very close now.  Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a segue created.  You can then pass the data using:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    SecondController *second = [segue destinationViewController];
    second.label.text = textBox.text;

}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! And one more question, does it works even when the segue is controlled by and IBAction button? Because now I'm getting the "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT" error when I press the button that controls the segue

Answer (score 0):

If you have the property of your label in your `SecondViewController`, you can use `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method to set its text after creating an instance of the `SecondViewController` and calling for its property as

```
`secondViewController.myLabel.text = @"some text";
```

If you have your label as an instance variable, pass the text using an `NSString` for the label's text to second view as

```
`secondViewController.txtStr=@"some text";
```

and in `SecondViewController`,set label's text in `viewDidLoad` method.